# Batch: backup, then delete old backup

Tags: windows, backup, batch, ftp

I have a batch script that runs hourly. It connects to an FTP server, downloads a backup file, then deletes the oldest backup (backups are kept for 4hours by default). This is supposed to insulate our facilities from a connection loss. It was brought to my attention that a facility lost their internet and was unable to make use of these backups because the script had deleted all the old ones 4hours after the connection went down. How can I modify this script to ONLY delete the oldest backup IF a new one is downloaded?

```
echo off

set FTPADDRESS=[omitted]
set FTPLOGIN=[omitted]
set FTPPASSWORD=[omitted]
set DIRECTORY=[omitted]

set BACKUP_FILE=emar_backup.zip
set DELETE_OLD_FILES_MIN=240

echo cd %DIRECTORY% > commands.txt
echo get %BACKUP_FILE% .\downloads\%BACKUP_FILE% >> commands.txt
echo put receipt.txt >> commands.txt
echo bye >> commands.txt

for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ('cscript //nologo getdate.vbs') do SET yymmdd_hhmmss=%%A

psftp.exe -2 -batch -b commands.txt -l %FTPLOGIN% -pw %FTPPASSWORD% %FTPADDRESS% > .\logs\lastlog.txt

cd downloads
if exist %BACKUP_FILE% ren %BACKUP_FILE% %BACKUP_FILE%-%yymmdd_hhmmss%.zip
..\DelOld.exe /f=* /m=%DELETE_OLD_FILES_MIN%
cd ..
```

Thanks in advance for anything you can contribute!

Comment: I'm confused how I can distinguish the OLD backup from the NEW. You can see in the last few lines that it changes the name of the NEW backup by calling the date/time... so if I call that current date and time in the next line (also adding an 'if' for a conditional delete), won't the date/time be wrong? DelOld.exe is kind of messing with the whole process, which I have no control over.

Comment: Perhaps I'm overthinking this. Will this work? if exist %BACKUP_FILE%-%yymmdd_hhmmss%.zip (..\DelOld.exe /f=* /m=%DELETE_OLD_FILES_MIN%)

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your own backup with a batch file there is a simple switch you need to add.  Example:

```
xcopy "c:\myfolder\*.*" "e:\myfolder\*.*" /s /d /f /y
```

- Switch `/S` copies all sub-directories of the folder.
- Switch `/d` will only copy files which were modified since the last backup.  (this switch overwrites the files with the newer information).  You can also use Switch /d:2/1/2020 to set the date to look for.  I have found the /d is better because you might miss new changes that happened between the last backup date and the specified date.
- Switch `/f` displays the files being copied, their location, and destination.
- Switch `/y` automatically overwrites the old file without asking you each time.

I have found that my backup files are kept up to date without wasting time by making several incremental backups.  No need to wipe any old files because the batch command replaces them with the newer information.

If you need more information on xcopy commands, [here is the link to the page](https://www.lifewire.com/xcopy-command-2618103).